# In powershell, how to let git ask for ssh key passphrase?

Tags: ssh, powershell, git

when I search the problem online, people always want to get rid of the ssh key passphrase prompt, but I have an opposite problem.

I am NOT using ssh-agent, and want windows to prompt ssh key passphrase everytime when I connect to the ssh server. It works fine with `ssh` command in powershell. But when I use `git clone ssh://myserver/repo.git`, there is no ssh key passphrase prompt and the connection is simply failed. I tried Powershell 5.x and 7.x and both gave me the same result:

```
> git clone ssh://myserver/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
myserver: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let git prompt ssh key passphrase in powershell, The environment variable `GIT_SSH` has to be set to `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`. After setting up this environment variable, powershell has to be **restarted** to use it.

You can either add the environment variable in Control Panel, or execute the following commands in powershell:

```
$SSHPath = (Get-Command -Name 'ssh.exe').Source
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('GIT_SSH', $SSHPath, 'User')
```

To verify you have successfully setup this environment variable, do the following in powershell:

```
> echo $env:git_ssh
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
```